# Testing JdbcTemplete.BatchUpdate method in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jdbctemplate

I am writing a JUnit test for testing the below method save in the `ExampleRepository` class,

```
@Repository
public class ExampleRepsoitory {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    String sql = "Select * from Hello";

    public void save(List<Course> listOfCourses) {

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {

                System.out.println("In Set Values Method");
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {

                System.out.println("In side getB");
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Below is the JUnit method,

```
@Test
public void testSave() throws Exception {

    List<Course> listofCourses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    Course course1 = new Course("Course1", "Spring", "10 Steps", Arrays
            .asList("Learn Maven", "Import Project", "First Example",
                    "Second Example"));
    Course course2 = new Course("Course2", "Spring MVC", "10 Examples",
            Arrays.asList("Learn Maven", "Import Project", "First Example",
                    "Second Example"));

    listofCourses.add(course1);
    listofCourses.add(course2);

    int[]  returnValue = {1,2,3};

    when(batchPreparedStatementSetter.getBatchSize()).thenReturn(5);

    when(jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, batchPreparedStatementSetter)).thenReturn(returnValue);

    exampleRepo.save(listofCourses);

}
```

I want to test the code in `setValue()` and `getBatchSize()`methods so that it will include my test coverage.

Please help, I tried with the above JUnit method but it's not working out.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. No need to write a test to figure that out: a batch update is supposed to update, but you're using a select query. Returning 0 from getBatchSize() doesn't make sense. The method doesn't do anything with its arguments. Start by documenting, and implementing, what the method should do. Then write a test that checks that it indeed does that. If it's supposed to insert each course into a table of your database, then call the method, then query your database to see if the courses have been inserted.

Comment: thing is, this is a sample example.. the code indeed inserts into the database when i executes.. but i want to cover the junit file of the repository with atleast 80% thats the reason i have posted a sample

Comment: Why don't you post the actual code, instead of this nonsensical code? But anyway, I repeat. If the contract of the method is to insert the courses, write a test that checks if the contract has been respected: it should call the method, then query the database, and see if the courses have indeed been inserted correctly.

Comment: the actual code is in office @JBNizet.. i am just trying to replicate it at home :)

Comment: u mean to say that covering junits for the anonymous class methods is not possible ??

Comment: No, not at all. I never said anything like that. I'll repeat once again. If the contract of the method, i.e. what would be in the javadoc if you wrote it, is to insert the courses; i.e. if the javadoc of the method is "Inserts all the courses of the given list of courses into the COURSES table", then that's what your JUnit test should check. And to do that, it should call the method with some courses, then query the database to see if the method indeed did what it's supposed to do: insert the courses. And of course, that will cover the code of the method, including the code of the inner class.

Comment: It seems you're trying to write JUnit tests only to mark the code as covered, without caring if the code indeed does what it's supposed to do. Don't do that. It's a waste of time.

Comment: Junits is about mocking the functionality i guess .. its not about insertion of data into the DB.. if i do that it will really work even with junits.. no problem with that.. i agree that i am looking for code coverage just for deployment into production... the problem is when i click on the coverage option in eclipse ..it is not covering the methods in anonymous class.. thats the problem

Comment: *Junits is about mocking the functionality i guess*. No. Not at all. First, it's JUnit. And JUnit is not a mocking framework. It's a test framework. If you write tests, write tests that make sense, or don't write tests at all. Writing tests that don't check anything is useless. All they do is adding a pile of code to maintain that doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issues of coverage, so posting a solution which worked for me.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String sql = "Select * from Hello";
    Mockito.doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
        //verify sql
        String sql1=invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
        assertEquals(sql,sql1);
        
        PreparedStatement arg0=Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
        BatchPreparedStatementSetter bpss=invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(1, BatchPreparedStatementSetter.class);
        bpss.setValues(arg0, 0);
        
        //verify batchsize
        int batchSize=bpss.getBatchSize();
        assertEquals(0,batchSize);
        
        //return whatever you want to return and assert accordingly outside
        return null;
        
    }).when(jdbcTemplate).batchUpdate(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(BatchPreparedStatementSetter.class));
    List<Course> listOfCourses=Arrays.asList(new Course());
    exampleRepo.save(listOfCourses);
```